What is the entropy source for this C function when compiled to .wasm using emscripten?
static inline void ed25519_randombytes(unsigned char *x,unsigned long long xlen)
{
  int i;

  if (ed25519_random_fd == -1) {
    for (;;) {
      ed25519_random_fd = open("/dev/urandom",O_RDONLY);
      if (ed25519_random_fd != -1) break;
      sleep(1);
    }
  }

  while (xlen > 0) {
    if (xlen < 1048576) i = xlen; else i = 1048576;

    i = read(ed25519_random_fd,x,i);
    if (i < 1) {
      sleep(1);
      continue;
    }

    x += i;
    xlen -= i;
  }
}

As you can see it uses this fd here. I am really interested how it works when compiled to wasm because this is a sys call ed25519_random_fd = open("/dev/urandom",O_RDONLY);
when I compiled it using emcc and executed in inside node or browser, it works, it produces random bytes. But not really sure how.

Have you tried examining the generated assembly code to see where it's reading from?

No I havent, I understand its binary format and that there are textual representations, but I was hoping I can avoid doing that, if someone already knows the answer

No need for reading binary. Compile c code with -S key - you will get a normal mnemonics of assembler code.

This would only give me mnemonics of assembler but not of wasm. I figured it out by digging in to emscripten source code, check out my answer

It surprising, that non-posix dev file like "/dev/urandom" is supported at all.

When your C function tries to read from /dev/urandom, it's ultimately using this randomFill function.
The source of entropy depends on the environment:
In a browser, it's crypto.getRandomValues()
In Node.js, it's either crypto.randomFillSync() or crypto.randomBytes()
Here is how I found out:
https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/58359bacef9654ea56a1c3805e998cf50c0955be/src/library.js#L1839
